# Was denied entry at South African airport and was issued these stamp

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, south-africa, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry at South African airport and was issued these stamps. Does this mean I can't use the visa again? It is a 3-year study permit.

[image]

Comment: The likely answer to your question is ‘yes’. Were you given any paperwork explaining the reason for the denial of entry and the repercussions?

Comment: Why have you waited five months to seek assistance regarding this? Why were you refused entry?

Comment: It's not a good idea to post personal data such as your passport number to the internet. I've edited your image to black those things out (and other things such as the barcode, which I assume encode similar information).

Comment: No I wasn't giving any paperwork but I saw them writhing on their on paper failed interview